# Словообразование - разные подходы (малозаметный, малоподвижный)

Tags: словообразование

На одном из ресурсов по русскому языку есть примеры словообразовательных разборов.
Так, слово малозаметный = мало + заметный, а малоподвижный = малый + подвижность.
Почему такие разные подходы к разбору по сути похожих слов? Почему малоподвижный не может быть образовано словами мало + подвижный? Чем можно помочь ученику 6 класса при словообразовательных разборах?

Малозаметный ← мало, заметный
Значение: признак малой заметности или малой значимости предмета или лица
Способ образования: сложение основ

Малоподвижный ← малый, подвижность
Значение: с малой подвижностью
Способ словообразования: сложение основ
Процесс, сопровождающий словообразование: вставка соединительной гласной о, усечение основы подвижность-

Comment: _Оксана62: На одном из ресурсов по русскому языку есть примеры словообразовательных разборов..._ === Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на этот ресурс.

Comment: http://russkiy-na-5.ru/dictionary/formations/%D0%BC

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, более логична в разборе слов ***малозаметный*** и ***малоподвижный***, по сравнению с позицией автора *«Словаря словообразовательных разборов»* ([http://russkiy-na-5.ru/dictionary/formations/м](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/dictionary/formations/%D0%BC)), откуда взята Ваша информация, позиция Тихонова, представленная в его *«Словообразовательном словаре русского языка»* (1990).

**У Тихонова:**

**заметить** –> замет-**н**(ый) –> мал-**о**-заметн(ый) –> малозаметн-**ость**;

**двигать** –> дви-**ну**-ть –> **по**-двинуть –> подви*г*-**а**-ть –> подви*ж*-**н**(ый) –> мал-**о**-подвижн(ый) –> малоподвижн-**ость**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]